# How to translate product name and info in Magento

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

Magento provide translation feature, a nice one for e-commerce platform.
But it seems to me that the translation is only for the predefined magento keyword, like 'add to cart', 'add to wishlist' etc and not for the product name, info, and description that the user input to the store.

Does anybody know how to implement this??

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although product attributes are not directly translated, you may be able to use the multi-store capability of Magento to accomplish the same thing. If you set up your different languages as different store views, you can change the relevant product attributes to "Store View" level and assign different values for each store. That way, product names and descriptions can be entered in their localized form and displayed properly.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

I read this thread with interest, because we just developed a Magento extension that lets users translate their store content and catalog without leaving the Magento platform.

[You can see the extension here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/lingotip/extension/4331/lingotip_translate).

Answer (score 0):

Transfluent makes a plugin that allows you to translate products, categories, tags and attributes for Magento. You can take a look at them here:

http://www.transfluent.com/en/products/magento/

They use crowdsourced translations via Gengo (www.gengo.com, shameless plug)